# 2016 Mini Cooper revs up to 2000rpm before dropping back down, why?

Tags: engine, idle, mini-cooper, surging

I have recently purchased a 2016 Mini Cooper with approximately 70,000 mileage. It has since developed some issues in the time since purchasing. When driving in eco mode the mini engine should shutoff when stationary and restart when put back in gear, however sometimes the car will not shut off in neutral and instead the revs will rise to 2000rpm before falling back to 1000, sometimes holding there for a few seconds before going back down, this also disables the stop start feature as can be seen on the dashboard. This only happens sometimes and sometimes the engines cuts out as it should when in neutral. After speaking to the car dealership they said this is normal and may be due to the car needing to warm up when starting. However this issue happens randomly, not just when the car first turns on but sometimes an hour or more into a journey and the car may be fine for the first hour of the journey. I am taking the car back to the garage to be looked at but want to know what the issue might be beforehand.

Apologies if this isn’t the right format, it’s my first question.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: I have a Subaru Crosstrek Sport, 2.5L CVT with auto stop start. When driving and coming to a stop (in gear) with brake pedal firmly depressed, A/S/S disables engine running. Releasing the brake pedal signals A/S/S to immediately restart the engine. I never shift into Park or neutral at any stop sign or light. Perhaps reviewing your owner's manual may help you understand how auto stop start operates within safe limits.